# Declaring global variables in android

Tags: android

I went through many pages, but couldn't understand properly how to declare a class to contain global variables and its declaration in manifest file (most important thing, need some extra concentration on that)

The class

```
global file
/**
 * 
 */
package com.furniture;


/**
 * @author sanketh
 *
 */
public class Gloabal extends ap{
       public String refer="";
       public int set=0;
       public String getData(){
         return this.refer;
       }

       public void setData(String d,int i){
         this.refer=d;
         set=i;
       }
    }
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.furniture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".Gloabal">



        <activity
            android:name="com.furniture.login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".passforgot"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".newuser"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".settings"></activity>

        <receiver android:name=".smsreciever"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

        </application>
</manifest>
somefile
package com.furniture;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

```
public class smsreciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    public String value;    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {

        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
//        Intent i1=new Intent();
            //((Gloabal)this.get).setData(str);
//            Gloabal g1=new Gloabal();
            Global g = (Global)getApplication();
            int data=g.getData();

            Log.v("sanketh","smsreciver value of str:"+str);
            int a=1;
            g1.setData(str,a);
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }                         
    }
}
```

Here i want to set the data to it...

```
Global g = (Global)getApplication(); // this line gives error for get application
```

Comment: Make a subclass of Application class, and define global variables in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using Application to create Global Variables, you can create a regular class to hold your variables. Right now, I am using this:

```
public class GlobalVar {


public String getGlobalVar1() {
    return GlobalVar1;
}

public void setGlobalVar1(String GlobalVar1) {
    this.GlobalVar1 = GlobalVar1;
}

private String GlobalVar1 = "";

 static {
    instance = new GlobalVar();

}

private GlobalVar() {
}

public static GlobalVar getInstance() {
    return GlobalVar.instance;
}
}
```

For setting a new value to your GlobalVar1 :

```
GlobalVar.getInstance().setGlobalVar1(value);
```

And for getting the value:

```
GlobalVar.getInstance().getGlobalVar1;
```

Answer (score 0):

public class GlobalState extends Application {

```
    private int gameScore = 0;

    public int getGameScore() {
        return gameScore;
    }

   public void setGameScore(int gameScore) {
       this.gameScore = gameScore;
   }

   public void incrementScore(){
       gameScore++;
  }
```

Manifest file

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:name="GlobalState" >

       <!-- component definitions -->
   </application>
```

Usage in Activity

```
GlobalState state = ((GlobalState) getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: my class doesnot extend the activity so how would i use it?

Comment: All you need is a context, cast it to activity class to which that context belongs and call `getApplicationContext()` on it